# Can anyone identify this biplane with distinct wind screen?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification, biplane

I'm trying to identify the aircraft in this photo of my great grandfather. The photo would have been taken during the mid to late 1920s, possibly early 1930s. He lived in Utah (not sure this helps?). It's hard to tell much from the cropped photo, but it's all I've got. It looks to have a distinct wind screen shape. Looks to be a biplane. Not sure what the logo/writing is on the fuselage. Any info or even guesses are greatly appreciated!

[image: Grandpa]

Comment: That fellow is Bill Devenish, you can read some of his recollections about the early days of the US Air Mail here - https://www.newspapers.com/clip/11948907/bill-devenish-pilot/

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the ..S Inc above the number 26, it seems that the operator is likely National Parks Airways Inc. / US Mail Contract [Air Mail Route 26](http://www.aerodacious.com/ccCAM026.HTM), ([more info](https://www.dreamsmithphotos.com/arrow/airmail_routes/route_21_30/26/cam_26.html)).

Your picture looks like this Stearman C3MB:

[image: Picture of a Steaman C3MB with National Parks logo]
Source: [Aerodacious](http://www.aerodacious.com/ccCAM026.HTM)

Here is another Stearman C3MB, National Parks Airways Inc had several of this aircraft:

[image: Picture of a Steaman C3MB with National Parks logo]

Source: [agefotostock.com](https://www.agefotostock.com/age/en/details-photo/stearman-c3mb-of-national-parks-airways/MEV-10943603)

Comment: Seriously... How do you do this???

Comment: @Freeman Mostly google + eye for detail + persistence.  Due to the persistence also experience, which helps. First thing I noted was the text on the aircraft. The letter style and the general style of the photo gave me more a late 20s feeling thana 30s feeling. So first google attempt: airplane 1925 utah. Searching for images. One of the first images showed a hangar with "national parks airways. inc" and upon closer inspection also "U.S. C.A.M. 26". Bingo! From there it was just researching that company, following leads, looking at historic aircraft registrations etc.

Comment: Nice. Almost need to post that as a "how to" any time someone uses [tag:aircraft-identification].